# FATAL:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(117)] No usable sandbox! puppeter

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, express, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer in the following project https://github.com/gatwirival/Whatsapp-api.git .It's working fine locally but during deployment in Heroku, it runs for a little while then crashes with the following error `FATAL:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(117)] No usable sandbox!`

App.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const fs = require('fs');
const createError = require('http-errors');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const { Client } = require('whatsapp-web.js');
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();

const SESSION_FILE_PATH = './session.json';
let sessionCfg;
if (fs.existsSync(SESSION_FILE_PATH)) {
  sessionCfg = require(SESSION_FILE_PATH);
}

const client = new Client({
  puppeteer: { headless: false }, // Make headless true or remove to run browser in background
  session: sessionCfg,
});

client.initialize();

client.on('qr', qr => {
  // NOTE: This event will not be fired if a session is specified.
  console.log('QR RECEIVED', qr);
  app.get('/getqr', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send({ qr });
  });
});

client.on('authenticated', session => {
  console.log('AUTHENTICATED', session);
  sessionCfg = session;
  fs.writeFile(SESSION_FILE_PATH, JSON.stringify(session), function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  });
});

client.on('auth_failure', msg => {
  // Fired if session restore was unsuccessfull
  console.error('AUTHENTICATION FAILURE', msg);
});

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('READY');
});
// Run `npm i qrcode-terminal` before this

const qrcode = require('qrcode-terminal')

client.on('qr', qr => {
  // NOTE: This event will not be fired if a session is specified.
  console.log('QR RECEIVED', qr);
  qrcode.generate(qr, { small: true }); 
  app.get('/getqr', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send({ qr });
  });
});

app.post('/sendmessage', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    // Magic happens here
  } catch (error) {
    next(error)
  }
})

app.post('/sendmessage', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { number, message } = req.body; // Get the body
    const msg = await client.sendMessage(`${number}@c.us`, message); // Send the message
    res.send({ msg }); // Send the response
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});
//puppeter
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){

  const browser = puppeteer.launch({
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
  });

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  let page;
  (async () => {
    page = await (await browser).newPage();
    await page.setContent(`<p>web running at ${Date()}</p>`);
    res.send(await page.content());
  })()
    .catch(err => res.sendStatus(500))
    .finally(async () => await page.close())
  ;
});

  console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", this.address().port, app.settings.env);
});
```

What I have tried:

Added the following code snippet and yet I get the error

```js
const browser = puppeteer.launch({
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
  });
```

After this failed I tried this.
-`sudo sysctl -w kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1`

to access the sandbox of chromium.